# How to get html document after IE navigates to a new page?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am using the code below

```
eSignIn.Click
Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    DoEvents     
Loop
Set html = IE.document
```

The html that i get is of the previous page not the new one which `IE` navigates to after the click event.

The state check loop is also being skipped even though `IE` is still loading, it works fine if put after `IE.navigate` command.

Even if i put a break before the `Set html = IE.document` statement and step into it after the page loads it still loads the document of previous page. Kindly let me know if some one has a solution.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible it's not really a new page but new content loaded into the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple workaround that i found.

```
IE.navigate "javascript:document.getElementById('clickelement').click();"
```

Regards